# Private NPM packages with google cloud functions has incorrect url, replacing / in package name with %!f(MISSING)

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I have my private NPM repo (using verdaccio) deployed on my private NAS and exposed publicly.

When I try to `npm install` it all works, but when I try to deploy my code with `firebase deploy`, or using app engine `gcloud app deploy` i get and error `FetchError: request to https://(nas-url-hidden-for-security-reasons)/@top%!f(MISSING)ui/-/ui-0.0.31.tgz failed`

It seems to be problem with `npm install` step. My package is called `@top/ui` and gcloud replaces it with `@top%!f(MISSING)ui`
If i take the error link and try to fix it manually, replacing package name, and open it in browser it works.

I have `.npmrc` in root of my project and in functions, so I dont think that it is a problem with auth, just package name is messed up